# Python 日付のフォーマット変換について

Tags: python, python3

CSVファイルのデータを抽出した日付のデータを変換した後に文字列の末尾を削除したいです。
`format="2021-06-03 12:10:10"`から`format="2021-06-03 12:1"` 日付の形式を変換したいですが、[:-1]を指定しても`format="2021-06-03 00:00"`になってしまいます。

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

**CSVのデータ:**

```
A         
2021-06-03 12:10:10
```

**フォーマットの変換後 (期待する結果):**

```
A         
2021-06-03 12:1
```

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs
from datetime import datetime as dt

with codecs.open(filename, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:
  df2 = pd.read_table(
    file, delimiter=",", parse_dates=['A'],
　　date_parser=lambda d: dt.strptime(d, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")[:-1]))
  print(df2)
```

Comment: `12:10:10`の10分10秒の部分が1桁の`1`になるのは、どういう考え方と計算によるものなのでしょうか？ 日付時刻の計算なのか、単なる文字列としての桁数削減なのか、それとも他の何かなのでしょうか？

Comment: @kunif ご回答ありがとうございます。`yyyy-m-d h:m`の形式で表示させたいので桁数削減しても`2021-06-03 00:00`になってしまいます。

Comment: pandasに日付時刻のデータとして読み込ませているので、そういう操作は意味が無いですね。日付時刻として読み込んだ後に、望むフォーマットの文字列データに変換すれば良いのでは？ それから10分10秒と1では値が変わってしまっているのでは？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html?highlight=read_table#pandas-read-table) の `date_parser` は文字列ではなく `datetime` 型のインスタンスを生成します。

> **date_parser**: function, optional
>
> Function to use for converting a sequence of string columns to an array of **datetime instances**.

出力結果の妥当性はともかく(実際には「分」を 10 分単位で round する？)、この場合には `converters` が適切でしょう。

```py
with codecs.open(filename, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:
  df2 = pd.read_table(
    file, delimiter=",",
    converters={
      "A": lambda d: dt.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")[:-1]
    })
  print(df2)

## 実行結果
                 A
0  2021-06-03 12:1
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。上記で問題なくできました。
因みに`2021-06-03 12:1`変換後に` df3 = df2[df2['A'].str.contains(time,na=True)].reset_index(drop=True)``の特定の日時を取得した後に`2021-06-03 12:10`の形式に戻したいはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、`df3.A += '0'` とする方法がありますが。。。

Comment: ありがとうございます。度々の質問になりますが、`df2.A += '0'`を追加後、`"%Y-%m-%d"`に戻したいですがうまく行かないです。こちらのように指定しましたが、エラーになってしまいます。。
`df2 = pd.read_table(file, delimiter="," ,parse_dates=['A'],
    date_parser=lambda d: dt.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))`

Comment: `df3=pd.to_datetime(df2['日時'], format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`こちらで試しましたら"%Y-%m-%d"に変換できますが、`0    2021-06-03
Name: 日時, dtype: object`と表示され全てのtable（列）が読み込まないようです。

Comment: 何がしたいのかよく判らないのですが、もう一度 CSV ファイルから読み込むのであれば、`converters` で `lambda d: dt.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` とすればよいのではないでしょうか(`[:-1]` を外す)。

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。0を追加後、`2021-06-03 12:10`このようになります。
その後に`2021-06-03`に変換したいです。0を追加しなくてもdf2.A[:-4]で`2021-06-03`に変換しようとしましたが、`2021-06-03`に変換されないです。最終的にconverters を行った後に特定の日付で検索後`"%Y-%m-%d"`に変更したいです。わかりにくい説明ですいません

Comment: これで良いのか判りませんが、`df2.A = df2.A.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])` でしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
こちらで問題なくできました。